# HTMLDOC script multi conversion

Tags: bash, scripting

I am trying to convert multiple htm files to pdf using HTMLDOC.
I can convert a single file with the following: `htmldoc --webpage -f filename.pdf sample/filename.htm`.

I try making a script and it seems to run but does not create the pdf files.

```
    for F in *; do
if [ "${F}" ]; then
    echo "${F}"   htmldoc --webpage -f /home/name/pdf/$F.pdf /home/name/sample/$F
fi
done
```

I would appreciate if someone would help me to get this working. I am not getting any errors other than not resulting in expected pdf files.

Thank you.

Jesse.

P.S.
I just noticed that the output from my script prefixes the filename on the command line that executes the program htmldoc.

```
computer1% ./convertpdf.sh
convertpdf.sh htmldoc --webpage -f /home/name/pdf/convertpdf.sh.pdf /home/name/oz-sample/convertpdf.sh
sample1.htm htmldoc --webpage -f /home/name/pdf/sample1.htm.pdf /home/name/oz-sample/sample1.htm
sample2.htm htmldoc --webpage -f /home/name/pdf/sample2.htm.pdf /home/name/oz-sample/sample2.htm
sample3.htm htmldoc --webpage -f /home/name/pdf/sample3.htm.pdf /home/name/oz-sample/sample3.htm
sample4.htm htmldoc --webpage -f /home/name/pdf/sample4.htm.pdf /home/name/oz-sample/sample4.htm
sample5.htm htmldoc --webpage -f /home/name/pdf/sample5.htm.pdf /home/name/oz-sample/sample5.htm
computer1%
```

I edited the script

```
for F in *; do
if [ "${F}" ]; then
    echo htmldoc --webpage -f /home/name/pdf/$F.pdf /home/name/sample/$F
fi
done
```

Now I get normal output but still no pdf.

```
computer1% ./convertpdf.sh
htmldoc --webpage -f /home/name/pdf/sample1.htm.pdf /home/name/oz-sample/sample1.htm
htmldoc --webpage -f /home/name/pdf/sample2.htm.pdf /home/name/oz-sample/sample2.htm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From any directory

```
htmdir="change this to directory of htm without final slash"
pdfdir="change this to pdf dir without final slash"  
for f in $htmdir/*.htm
do
  if [ -f $f ]
  then
    fname=$(basename "$f")
    echo converting $f to $pdfdir/${fname%.*}.pdf
    htmldoc --webpage -f $pdfdir/${fname%.*}.pdf $f
  fi
done
```

Comment: I will try this version and let you know.

Comment: This worked quite well and gave feedback on each file. Would you be able to suggest how It could be run from outside the directory that contains the files I am converting without including that in the path of the destination pdf files?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I found that because I was echoing it wasn't actually running the htmldoc command it was just echoing the command string to console.
I removed the echo and it created the pdf files.

Now to figure out how to get it to run from outside the directory where the source files are. when I call it from the directory above it includes the path I set in the command and creates an invalid command string.